# Pagenavi by multiple field search wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search

I am using the pagenavi plugin and mutiple search by taxonomy and acf custom field. However pagenavi is not working on the query search.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts','nt_custom_search_filter');
function nt_custom_search_filter( $query ) {

if( $query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {

    if( isset($_GET['s'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'product' ) );// box text search
    }
    if( $query->is_main_query() ) { 
        $args[] = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );
        if( isset( $_GET[ 'product_cat' ] ) && $_GET[ 'product_cat' ] != 'all' ) {

            $args[] = 
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_GET['product_cat']
                
            );
        }$query->set( 'tax_query', $args );
            $meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );
            if( isset( $_GET[ 'status' ] ) && $_GET[ 'status' ] != 'all' ) {
                $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key' => 'status',
                    'value' => $_GET['status'],
                    'compare' => '='
                );
            }
            $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

    }
}
return $query;}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “*not working*”? That tells us nothing about what is happening or what you have found out about the problem already yourself. We can’t help you fix a problem if we don’t know what it is!

Comment: pagenavi not working. page 2 search page notification 404 not foud

Answer (score 0):

To solve possible problems with an incorrect calculation of the pagination in WP_Query, you need three additional arguments: `posts_per_page`, `paged` and `offset`

In `$count` we save the number of posts per page, or just use the default which you have set in your wordpress backend under the settings.

`$paged` tells us which page the user is currently on.

With `$offset` you calculate how many contributions the loop should be moved.

So you can adjust the `$args[]` in your `$query`. Code can look like:

```
  $count = get_option('posts_per_page', 25); // get 25 posts
  $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $offset = ($paged - 1) * $count;

  $args = array (
     'posts_per_page' => $count,
     'paged' => $paged,
     'offset' => $offset,
     'relation' => 'AND'
     .
     . /* other arguments */
     :
  );
```

---

### Edit:

so your code can look like the following. Please notice, that the code is not tested.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts','nt_custom_search_filter');
function nt_custom_search_filter( $query ) {

if( $query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {

    if( isset($_GET['s'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'product' ) );// box text search
    }
    if( $query->is_main_query() ) { 

        $count = get_option('posts_per_page', 25); // get 25 posts
        $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $offset = ($paged - 1) * $count;

        $args[] = array( 'posts_per_page' => $count, 'paged' => $paged, 'offset' => $offset, 'relation' => 'AND' );
        if( isset( $_GET[ 'product_cat' ] ) && $_GET[ 'product_cat' ] != 'all' ) {

            $args[] = 
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_GET['product_cat']
                
            );
        }$query->set( 'tax_query', $args );
            $meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );
            if( isset( $_GET[ 'status' ] ) && $_GET[ 'status' ] != 'all' ) {
                $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key' => 'status',
                    'value' => $_GET['status'],
                    'compare' => '='
                );
            }
            $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

    }
}
return $query;}
```

Comment: Could you please give me the full code?  I don't know how to apply your code

Comment: I added the code to your code. I cannot test it, but it looks alright.

Comment: not woking. Maybe I'm missing something on the search page (search.php). This is my code

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <?php the_title();?>
  <?php endwhile; 
  wp_pagenavi();
  ?>